# Overflow:hidden and :after pseudo-selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before I start my question I would like to state that I have seen similar questions like this. All of them say that either add `position:relative` to the container of remove `position:absolute` from the `:after` selector but none of them worked for me.

This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s5zg315t/).

When I try to add `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis;` then arrow to the right of the div disappears or the `:after` selector disappears. I do not know why is this happening.

What's causing the problem and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Please add the relevant code to the question as well.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You haven't really made it clear what your goal is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think, its possible through CSS, if you keep your HTML structure like this, better make a minor change in your HTML

Simply, **add another element inside your P tag** and add `text-overflow` css to that element, it fixes all your issue

```css
.skills {
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.skill {
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Gotham-Medium';
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.skill p {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
.skill p span { /* added a new element, and wrapped it*/
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100%;
}
.skill p:after {
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-width: 35px;
  margin-top: -35px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.skill.orange {
  background: rgba(242, 192, 30, 0.3);
}
.skill.orange p {
  width: 45%;
  background: rgb(242, 192, 30);
}
.skill.orange p:after {
  border-left-color: rgb(242, 192, 3);
}
.skill.light-blue {
  background: rgba(73, 180, 232, 0.3);
}
.skill.light-blue p {
  width: 15%;
  background: rgb(73, 180, 232);
}
.skill.light-blue p:after {
  border-left-color: rgb(73, 180, 232);
}
.skill.dark-blue {
  background: rgba(67, 93, 155, 0.3);
}
.skill.dark-blue p {
  width: 35%;
  background: rgb(67, 93, 155);
}
.skill.dark-blue p:after {
  border-left-color: rgb(67, 93, 155);
}
.skill.red {
  background: rgba(230, 74, 58, 0.3);
}
.skill.red p {
  width: 55%;
  background: rgb(230, 74, 58);
}
.skill.red p:after {
  border-left-color: rgb(230, 74, 58);
}
.skill.purple {
  background: rgba(43, 59, 96, 0.3);
}
.skill.purple p {
  width: 85%;
  background: rgb(43, 59, 96);
}
.skill.purple p:after {
  border-left-color: rgb(43, 59, 96);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="content-section">
  <div class="row skills">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill orange arrow-right" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Zencart Development big texttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill orange" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>PHP</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill light-blue" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>HTML5 / CSS</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill light-blue" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Javascript</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill dark-blue" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>E-Commerce</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill dark-blue" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Content Writing</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill red" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Wordpress</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill red" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Drupal Development</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill purple" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Keyword Optimization</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 ">
      <div class="skill purple" data-progress="30">
        <p>
          <span>Photoshop 6 suit</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui check the text written in bold just above my code! I have added a `span` tag inside `P` and also have added comment in CSS.

Comment: I am asking for the explanation of adding a span tag. Why didn't it worked for the P tag?

Comment: coz, you were giving `overflow:hidden` to that `p` tag itself which had text, which caused the `:after` property to be chopped out as it was moving out of its box-size. hence to preserve the `:after {arrow code}`, prevent giving `overflow:hidden` to it, add an extra element inside it and give it `overflow and wrap` properties.